# Failed to change color over time in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am studying OpenGL using OpenGL superbible 7th edition. However, when I tried to run the example in Chapter 2, I found a problem that the color is not changing over time as intended.

Here is the main program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return 1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "My First OpenGL Project", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open window\n");
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gl3wInit();

    bool running = true;

    do
    {
        double current_time = glfwGetTime();
        static const GLfloat color[] = {
            (float)sin(current_time) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
            (float)cos(current_time) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
            0.0f,
            1.0f };
        std::cout << current_time << std::endl;
        std::cout << color[0] << std::endl;
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        running &= (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_RELEASE);
        running &= (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != GL_TRUE);
    } while (running);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

It appears that the value of current_time is changing over time but the value of color[0] is not. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because initializers for static variables are only called once when the variable is initialized. Also the const is a good hint that this variable will never change.

So if you want a different color in every frame, remove the `static const` and stick with

```
GLfloat color[] = {
        (float)sin(current_time) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
        (float)cos(current_time) * 0.5f + 0.5f,
        0.0f,
        1.0f };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice that it was a static variable.

Comment: I can't believe I managed to miss the `static`. Btw you might make it `const GLfloat color[]` since a new variable is being allocated on the stack in every iteration of the loop and you actually don't modify it later.